# How to prohibit the use of global variables on compile time

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

Is there a way to prohibit the use of global variables?

I want GCC to generate an error on compile time when a global variable is defined.

We have a code that should be run per thread and want to allow only use of stack (which is thread safe)

Is there way to enforce it ?

Some GCC flag or other way to verify it ?

Comment: Does not seem so from [this feature request](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46097)

Comment: I don't believe this is currently possible.  It would not be *that* difficult to add, and others might be interested, so I suggest you rephrase this as a feature request and send it to the mailing list `gcc-help@gcc.gnu.org`.

Comment: What is a global variable? Is a static variable inside a function a global variable? Answer: No, but it falls within your "definition" for one. To go one step further, if I have a stack pointer to a heap allocated memory block, is that a pointer to a "global" variable or transitively a global variable itself? How in the world can the compiler track such things?

Comment: Well, anything allocated via `malloc` is not on the stack either, so... but seriously, global variables are a legitimate thing in the C language, and while often being disputed (both for good reasons and religious reasons), they are still often useful. I doubt a compiler manufacturer would implement a "feature" to break the compiler's language compliance on such a crucial feature. That would be like disallowing the use of `float` or `const char*`.

Comment: Why not just not use global variables? It's actually hard to declare one “accidently”, so you don't need any help from the compiler.

Comment: @Damon: On platforms that don't have hardware floating point, it would indeed be quite useful to have the compiler disable `float` and `double` as built-in types.

Comment: @Novelocrat Just because there's no hardware support, you may still want to be able to use floating-point types (even if it's slower). If you disagree with a (useful) language feature, don't buthcher the compiler - just don't use that feature or use a macro to issue a warning when that feature is used.

Answer (score 19):

One approach would be to generate a linker map file (e.g. pass option **-Wl,-Map,program.map** to gcc), and examine the **.data** and **.bss** output sections for any contributions from the object files that you want to run without globals.

For instance, if my source file **hello.c** has:

```
static int gTable[100];
```

the linker map file will have something like this in it:

```
.bss            0x0000000000600940      0x1b0
 *(.dynbss)
 .dynbss        0x0000000000000000        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
 *(.bss .bss.* .gnu.linkonce.b.*)
 .bss           0x0000000000600940        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o
 .bss           0x0000000000600940        0x0 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o
 .bss           0x0000000000600940        0x1 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/crtbegin.o
 *fill*         0x0000000000600941       0x1f 00
 .bss           0x0000000000600960      0x190 hello.o
```

You can see that **hello.o** is contributing 0x190 (400) bytes to the **.bss** section. I've used the approach of parsing a link map file with a Python script to generate code size and RAM usage metrics for an embedded project with reasonable success in the past; the text output format from the linker is pretty stable.

Comment: Using a linker script, you could also turn the presence of `.data` sections into an error -- you'd map them to a zero-length output area.

Comment: +1 This answer and Simon's comment are the proper ingredients for enforcing a non-globals rule in your build system.

Comment: @SimonRichter can you please provide an example on how to map / limit the size of the bss/data segments using a linker script ?

Comment: Variant 1: `ASSERT(SIZEOF(.data)) == 0, "No global data allowed")`

Comment: Variant 2: `MEMORY { NONE : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 0 }`, followed by `.data { ... } >NONE`

Comment: For this, you'd need to arrange for nothing in the program to need static data or BSS. When I tried this, **crtbegin.o** was needing 8 bytes for a __dso_handle pointer.

Answer (score 9):

No such functionality in gcc. Some workaround would be to incorporate in the build process a static analysis tool which can detect globals. Still the compilation would not fail, but at least you would be warned in some way. I can see that PC-Lint (www.gimpel.com) has a check for

> non const non volatile global variables, locating these can assist multi-threaded applications in detecting non re-entrant situations

Probably other tools may include similar functionality.

Comment: I was thinking about using nm or objdump to scan for global variables and print a warning

Comment: That would work and looks easier. Similarly to static analysis solution you will need to filter out the globals from runtime library.

Comment: The compilation might not fail, _per se_, but this check could be incorporated into the Makefile such that it would cause the compile step of the build to fail. Alternatively, one could write a `fake_gcc` wrapper script that would call the real compiler and then do the check; this way, you could make it look like the compile was failing.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/index.html) to extract the symbols from the source code and then search the output with a (perl or python) script for global variables.

E.g. following line would tell you whether a C soucre file `hello.c` contains global variables:

```
ctags -f- hello.c | perl -ne"@a=split(/\t/, $_); if ($a[3] eq qq(v)){ print qq(Has global variables.); exit 0; }"
```